# If i delete the faces on the front side, on the back side they aren't deleted

Tags: faces

I'm stuck at following problem:

I have the following mesh and the front side:

[image: this at fron tside blender]

And this at back side:

[image]

If i delete the faces on the front side, on the back side they aren't deleted.

How can I have the same faces on front and backside ? Or delete the faces for front and back?

many thanks

Comment: The simplest answer is that front and back are different faces, not one. You would need to select both and delete. If you switch to wireframe mode you should be able to visualize and select the faces correctly.

Comment: ok, could it be possible to make the back face same as the front ?

Comment: if you want the front and back side of your wall to have the same topology, build you wall without any thickness, then extrude (or use Solidify modifier and apply it)